# RPC Response format in RESTful API

Tags: rest, rpc, restful-architecture, json-api

I am designing an API and trying to stick to [json-api](http://jsonapi.org/) for the output format. I need to provide a service endpoint like: `resource/1/do-something-complicated`. I was wondering if there are any best practices for the response format to send to this sort of request since it does not do traditional CRUD on a "resource". Doesn't need to be json-api specific. Just wondering in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spec website seems to have some vague suggestions on [asynchronous processing](http://jsonapi.org/recommendations/#asynchronous-processing). That looks to boil down to a `POST /resource` and response of `202 Accepted` and then a `Content-Location` header on where to check status. The payload itself is not described at all.

I would try something like accepting a `POST` at your `/resource` a payload such as

```
{
    "data": {
        "attributes": {
            "type": "some-complicated-process",
            "id": 1
        }
    }
}
```

This would then return a url for checking the status of the job.

Comment: Thanks. Missed the suggestions section completely.